# xcode - transition - reload IUWebView

Tags: webview, reload, reset, back

I am using a go back transition on a button for my app and it goes back as expected to the previous IUWebView but it doesn't reload or refresh the webpage but rather shows the prior user entry which causes the app to glitch.

The glitch would not happen if the page was refreshed. Is there a way to go back but for the IUWebView to reload the page instead of going back without refreshing so that the old content is removed and a new entry can be entered without problems?

I am using:

**[page loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL :[NSURL URLWithString:@"........"]]];
    [super viewDidLoad];**

I want the page to be reset when I press the button - Touch Up Inside - Web View goBack

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the previous url in NSString/NSURL using the following method of the UIWebViewDelegate and refresh the page using the same method after the back button is invoked.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

see [UIWebViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)